# What is the exact meaning of "no sooner ~ than" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> He found the tinder-box, but ***(1) no sooner had he struck a few sparks from the flint and steel, than the door flew open and the dog with eyes as big as teacups***, whom he had seen while down in the tree, ***stood before him***, and said, “What orders, master?”
>
> “Hallo,” said the soldier; “well this is a pleasant tinderbox, if it brings me all I wish for.”
>
> “Bring me some money,” said he to the dog.
>
> He was gone in a moment, and presently returned, carrying a large bag of coppers in his month. The soldier very soon discovered after this the value of the tinder-box. ***(2) If he struck the flint once, the dog who sat on the chest of copper money made his appearance; if twice, the dog came from the chest of silver; and if three times, the dog with eyes like towers, who watched over the gold.***
>
> Source : The tinder-box by Hans Christian Andersen

At (1), how many times had he struck the spark after all?

My dictionary says that ***"no sooner ~ than = after"***.

According to (2), for there had been ***a few*** sparks, all three dogs had to make their appearances, but only one dog had appeared.

I don't understand well. Please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really about English, but about how you light a fire with a **flint and steel**...

A flint and steel are struck together, over some **tinder**, or easily combustible material. When the right sort of stone strikes the right sort of metal, **sparks** fly, and if one falls on the tinder, the tinder may catch fire.

Each strike can scatter several sparks.